# how to flatten out the middle part of landscape

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I made a landscape using ANT landscape add-on. Here's what I have:[image]

What I want to do is to flatten out the middle part, to render sth like a valley. Specifically, the area that I circled below: [image]

How do I go about doing this? (btw I don't necessarily have to use ANT landscape).

EDIT:
If I use S+Z+0, I get this: [image]
where vertices are not at z=0, instead just levels the vertices I've selected. How can I set vertices to 0?

EDIT2: I tried setting the z values to 0 for the selected vertices. As yo can see they are stretched equally but are not at z=0. In fact, the top right panel seems to set the 'median' of the vertices, not individual vertices... How do I set them to 0 using to transform tool?
[image]

Comment: Sculpting would be the second option. You could go into "sculpt mode" and use the "smooth" brush on that area.

Comment: @moonboots I'm sorry but I'm new to blender and I tried S+Z+0 in edit mode but it didn't place vertex at 0. How exactly do I set vertex z location to 0?

Comment: sorry I meant select a vertex on the centre of the area that you want to make flat, enable the proportional editing option (play with the mouse wheel to increase or decrease the influence zone), then S+Z+ drag the cursor to flatten

Comment: is there a way i can set them to 0?

Comment: Make sure you are using the pivot point you intended before you scale. But after they are all flat (and before you change the selection mode--this works correctly only for Cursor pivot in this context if you are using proportional editting), press the N key to bring up the Info panel and change the Z coordinate value to "0".

Answer (score 3):

Select the vertices you want to be leveled, set 3D cursor to world origin, change pivot point to 3D cursor, S+Z+0. Don't forget to reset pivot point, or other things could go wrong. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I second this but will add that if you want a smooth falloff, use soft-selection or vertex/weight painting. You can also set the pivot to Median instead of Cursor, scale to zero, and translate all the points to the desired plane.

Comment: How do I change the pivot point to 3d cursor? I'm using blender 2.8. Is it in layout mode?

Comment: S+Z+0, and then setting the median to 0 worked.

Comment: @MoneyBall It's in the top middle of the viewport.